# How to fix an Empty output for STDERR?

Tags: python, stderr

My program is working well and its printing the correct STDOUT but for STDERR I'm getting  ''Empty output stream''

can anyone fix my code?, I'm stuck here.

Input

```
285 242 2053   260 310 450   10   682
```

Output

```
207229
```

My code

```
def sum_leaves(K, inputs, count=1):    
    A, B, M, L1, L2, L3, D, R = map(int, inputs)
    x = (((A*K)+B) % M)
    y = (((A*K)+2*B) % M)

    if K < L1 or count == D:
        my_list.append(K)
    elif L1 <= K < L2:
        sum_leaves(x, inputs, count + 1)
    elif L2 <= K < L3:
        sum_leaves(y, inputs, count + 1)
    elif L3 <= K:
        sum_leaves(x, inputs, count + 1)
        sum_leaves(y, inputs, count + 1)
    if count == 1:
        return sum(my_list)


def read_input(input_string):
    inputs = input_string.split()
    A, B, M, L1, L2, L3, D, R = map(int, inputs)
    x = (((A*R)+B) % M)
    y = (((A*R)+2*B) % M)

    if L1 <= R < L2:
        return sum_leaves(x, inputs)
    elif L2 <= R < L3:
        return sum_leaves(y, inputs)
    elif L3 <= R:
        sum_leaves(x, inputs)
        return sum_leaves(y, inputs)

my_list = []
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(read_input(input()))
```

Comment: Why do you expect `stderr` output? Your program doesn't print to `stderr`. "Empty output stream" is probably coming from whatever you're using to run this script, the script itself doesn't care if `stderr` is "empty" or not.

Comment: I'm fairly new to python, but I don't see any code that is trying to print to STDERR, so why do you expect output on STDERR?

Comment: I'm uploading my code into an automatic evaluate and it check's the stdout and stderr

Answer (score 2):

You aren't sending anything to `stderr`. `print()` sends to `stdout`. Use `print("error", file=sys.stderr)` to send to `stderr`.

Comment: Assuming this is Python 3 anyway. The tags don't specify, and there is no unique Py3 syntax here (the parens around a single `print` "argument" would work identically in Py2 and Py3, they're just superfluous in Py2).

Comment: I'm uploading my code into an automatic evaluate and it check's the stdout and stderr

Comment: your solution is not helpful ,please delete it